# Sort all files in subfolders by type

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, sorting

So I have a folder with several subfolders containing photos and videos (mainly but not exclusively, `.jpg` and `.mp4` respectively).

I want all files in every subfolder (of the folder in question, **NOT** everywhere on Windows in general, otherwise I'd be able to do that by changing sorting criteria universally), stay where they are but **sorted in groups of their type (photos first then videos i.e. type rather than extension distinction), alphabetically.**

As an example, in the folder **"`Ferrari`"** we got the following files:

```
Monza1.mp4
Monza2.jpeg

Portofino in action.mp4
Portofino in action.jpg

Roma5.mkv
Roma6.jpeg

...
...
```

All files sorted alphabetically by name/default

I wanted them sorted like:

```
Monza2.jpeg
Portofino in action.jpg
Roma6.jpeg
```

Photos were grouped together, moved in the beginning then sorted alphabetically.

```
Monza1.mp4
Roma5.mkv
```

Videos followed in the same manner.

Is this possible?

Any cmd, bat file or even third party program suggestion would do.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

So, you can define your order using:

- **`For /F`** loop (**`your,order,itens...`**) `Do` **`Dir /OrderName`** (`/ON`):

---

- Command line:

```bat
for %i in (mp4,mpg,mpeg,wmv,m4v,jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp3,m4a)do 2>nul dir /on /a-d /b "%Userprofile%\pictures\*.%~i"
```

- **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file:

```bat
@echo off

set "_dir=%Userprofile%\Some\Target\Folder\"
set "_order=mp4,mpg,mpeg,wmv,m4v,jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp3,m4a"

for %%i in (%_order%)do 2>nul dir /a-d /on /b "%_dir%*.%%~i"
```

For each item in variable "**`%_order%`**", the command in **`do()`**
becomes:

```bat
   Dir Displays a list of files andsubdirectories in a directory.
    /A Displays files with specified attributes.
     - Prefix meaning not
     D Attributes   D  Directories

    /O List by files in sorted order.
     N Sortorder  N  By name (alphabetic)
    /B Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

%_dir% Full\Path\To\Target\Folder e.g. "%Userprofile%\Media"
  %~i  The current eXtension (ending .string) in loop, e.g. mp4
*.%~i  All files with the eXtension from actual item in loop list by Order Name...
```

```bat
> For %i in (mp4,mkv)do Dir /A-D /ON /B "%_dir%*.%~i"

is the same ::  Dir /A-D /ON /B "%Userprofile%\Media\*.mp4"
is the same ::  Dir /A-D /ON /B "%Userprofile%\Media\*.mkv"

Monza1.mp4
Roma5.mkv
```

- **Obs.:** Use **`2>nul`** only to avoid output error if any extension/file does not exist/list

---

- Another option will be....

```bat
for %i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,y,w,z)do @dir /on /b "C:\Some\Folder\*.%~i????" 2>nul

for %i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,gif,h,i,j,k,l,mp4,mpeg,mov,m4v,m4a,n,ogv,oga,opus,p,q,r,spx,s,t,u,v,x,y,wmv,z)do @dir /on /b "C:\Some\Folder\*.%~i????" 2>nul
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [The Complete List of Video File Formats and Codecs for Developers](https://blog.filestack.com/thoughts-and-knowledge/complete-list-audio-video-file-formats/)